# Is it possible to call a Rails 3 controller within Rack middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, controller, middleware

I want to use ExtDirect for a 3rd party extjs user interface in Rails 3. So I have started to update the active-direct gem to work with Rails 3. Here is the updated version: https://github.com/stonegao/active-direct

At the moment my modified active direct plugin/gem works with models. I'm able to do this in JavaScript:

```
App.namespace.Project.all({params},callback_function);
```

That's great.

Now I want to use some special Rails 3 controllers (that act like a service).

In my Extdirect JS is this:

```
App.mynamespace.MyProject_Controller_V1_workspaceController.getStatus
```

This response also comes to my extjs router. No I want call this controller action and get the response.

I can't use `@app.call(env)` with a changed request_uri because I have no match in routes.rb

Is it possible to call this controller action

Specification of extdirect: http://tinyurl.com/4y3nc44

Thanks skeller1

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is!

just do something like this:

```
status,headers,response=ProjectsController.action("index").call(@env)
```

so you can call the index method of the ProjectsController.

beware: ExtDirect accepts all types in the HTTP_ACCEPT http header field.
so you can do a

```
 @env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "application/json"
```

before your request to an action to set your wanted response type.